# What's the difference between ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int) and ctypes.c_int * 5?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to call a python function (a callback) from C++ with ctypes. The python function accept an array of ints as parameters. I need to access this array in python.

c code

```c
typedef void (*FooFunc)(int*, int*);
void runfoo(FooFunc foo_func) {
  int dims[5] = {3, 5, 1, 1, 1};
  foo_func(dims, dims);
}
```

python code

```py
def foo(dims1, dims2):
    x = dims1[0]
    y = dims1[1]
    z = dims1[2]
    print(x, y, z)
    x = dims2[0]
    y = dims2[1]
    z = dims2[2]
    print(x, y, z)


libc = ctypes.CDLL('./libpath.so')
protofoo = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int * 5, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
libc.runfoo(protofoo(foo))
```

It gives
(-333106720, 32766, -333106720)
(3, 5, 1).

What's the difference between ctypes.c_int * 5 and ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int) in prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.int)` is equivalent to `int*`.

`ctypes.c_int * 5` is a type equivalent to the type of `int arr[5]`.  It's implementation doesn't decay to a pointer as a parameter like C, so it looks like when using it as a parameter it expects an array to be passed by value on the stack.  I tested that below by printing the address of `dims` in hex in C and you can see its 64-bit pointer value is the first two 32-bit elements returned to python when displayed as hexadecimal:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*FooFunc)(int*, int*);
__declspec(dllexport) void runfoo(FooFunc foo_func) {
  int dims[5] = {3, 5, 1, 1, 1};
  printf("%p\n",dims);
  foo_func(dims, dims);
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes

def foo(dims1, dims2):
    x = dims1[0]
    y = dims1[1]
    z = dims1[2]
    print(f'{x:08X} {y:08X} {z:08X}')
    x = dims2[0]
    y = dims2[1]
    z = dims2[2]
    print(f'{x:08X} {y:08X} {z:08X}')

libc = ctypes.CDLL('test')
protofoo = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int * 5, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
libc.runfoo(protofoo(foo))
```

**Output**

```
000000FD6E1EED00
6E1EED00 000000FD 6E1EED00
00000003 00000005 00000001
```

Comment: Just curious, If I insist on the use of ctypes.c_int * 5 as the CFUNCTYPE, what param shall I pass on the cpp side to make it work as expected? That is, foo_func(?, dims) to make it work. An example would be appreciated.